# Regrouping sum all duplicate Value in Panda

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a dataframe in Panda with the number of cows stolen per Year :

```
    stolen_each_year = data[['stolen cows','year_of_date' ]]
```

I would like to remove all Duplicate years and keep just one with the sum of all.
I have an idea with a python function but I am trying to use the panda at the maximum
[image]

Thank You for your time

EDIT : I tried with the .groupby method but it does not seem to work fine
[image: After using the groupby method]

Comment: assign back `stolen_each_year = stolen_each_year.groupby("year_of_date")['stolen cows'].sum()`

Answer (score 2):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) the *stolen cows*.

`stolen_each_year.groupby("year_of_date")['stolen cows'].sum()`

---

also... interesting dataset ...